# "Set document metadata failed" when I run sudo gedit

Tags: 16.04, command-line, sudo, gedit, metadata

I have upgraded 14.04 to 16.04 . Now I am trying to open the gedit from terminal by passing the command:

```
sudo gedit /some/where/file.txt
```

but it is throwing an error stating that:

```
(gedit:2090): Gtk-WARNING : Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown:
  The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files**
```

However, it is opening the file. When I try to save any modification then it is showing this error after saving the file:

```
(gedit:2090): WARNING : Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported
```

I am not getting why this is happening in 16.04 only; it was not on 14.04.

Comment: It's just a warning, but it is slightly misleading. There is nothing wrong really. You always get this kind of notices if you open a GTK app from the command line.

Comment: Of interest: [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)

Answer (score 8):

You can stop seeing this behavior simply by launching gedit from the launcher rather than the command line as was intended.

If you indeed require an editor that you can launch from the command line without seeing these errors, you might try `nano` or `pico`(a simple to use editor) launched from the command line or `vi` (a more advanced editor) also launched from the command line.

for more info on these editors see `man nano` or `man vi` respectively.

Most people love one and hate the other but you have the freedom to [choose](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/general-10/nano-vs-vi-589300/)

Source: Experience

Answer (score 5):

You can ignore those warnings.
If it bothers you, just type:

```
sudo -H gedit /some/where/file.txt &>/dev/null
```

Comment: And how to configure things to permanently stop seeing them?

Comment: the warnings are part of gedit.
you can write a shell script gedit in the path before the original gedit and do the redirect of the output.
I dont believe there are other ways, just this or a similar workaround

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5IJc.png)

In my case, I was able to remove it by putting &>/dev/null on similar warnings.

Answer (score -1):

Hay every one,
I have solved this issue with typing like this command:

sudo gedit //some/where/file.txt

It means you should put one / before typing file address