# I'm trying to change my PS1 using sudo gedit /etc/bashrc and I get messages in the terminal

Tags: bash, sudo, bashrc

I used this command to change the PS1 settings

```
sudo gedit /etc/bashrc
```

When I change my PS1 settings I get this. See also [my question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1022512/793773) earlier today to see the whole problem I have

```
(gedit:10788): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

[image: warnings]

Comment: See ["Set document metadata failed" when I run sudo gedit](//askubuntu.com/q/798935) for the reason for the message, which is not very serious. However, why on earth are you editing `/etc/bashrc` to set your PS1?

Comment: @Zanna i saw this on this [tutorial] (https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)

Comment: Well, you should instead edit your local `~/.bashrc`. But, I think you had better edit your other question and try to explain in more detail how you got into this situation...

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy-paste the text, and use the formatting tools to make it look nice. (For more details, see [Why do people post screenshots of their terminals?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/301745))

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). You actually need to edit the file ~/.bashrc, not /etc/bash.bashrc.

But if you do need to edit a system file, don't use `sudo gedit`. Instead use a command-line editor like `nano`, i.e. `sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc`.

For more details, see ["Set document metadata failed" when I run sudo gedit](https://askubuntu.com/q/798935/301745)